# If $(X,O_X)$ is a scheme, and $Y$ is Zariski closed, the elements which vanish on $U\cap Y$ form an ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $(X,O_X)$ be a scheme, and $Y$ be a Zariski closed subset. For any $U$ we define $I(U)$ to be the subset of $O_X(U)$ which vanish on $U\cap Y$.

My main question is what does this even mean? I initially thought that $I(U)$ was the kernel of the restriction map $\operatorname{res}^U_{U\cap Y}$ but then realized that doesn't make sense since $U\cap Y$ is not necessarily open in $X$, so what does it mean for an element to vanish on $U\cap Y$? If I was dealing with a sheaf of say continuous functions to $\mathbb{R}$, then there is a nice evaluation map that makes sense, but since the ring $O_X(U)$ can't be identified in such a way, I am at a a loss of what to do. Once I know that I am sure I can show that $I(U)$ is an ideal, I just don't get what this means.

Comment: If you have some point $x\in X$, you also obtain a map corresponding to 'evaluation at $x$': for any open subset $U\subseteq X$ containing $x$ we define $\operatorname{ev}_x:\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to k(x)$ by $s\mapsto s_x+\mathfrak{m}_{X,x}$, where $s_x$ is the stalk at $x$ (so an element of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$), $\mathfrak{m}_{X,x}$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and $k(x)=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_{X,x}$ is the residue field. Then, you can define $I(U)=\{s\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)\mid \operatorname{ev}_x(s)=0\forall x\in Y\cap U\}$.

Comment: @imtrying46 ok so I see that the stalk at $x$ should be the localization of a ring corresponding to an open neighborhood of $x$ of the form Spec $A$, but if we had another open set that was the form Spec $B$ containing $x$ how do we know that these give the same stalk?

Comment: The stalk is intrinsically defined for $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, not only by referencing some affine neighbourhoods. To define it hands on, rather than just writing down some colimit, you may construct it as follows: consider the set $S_{X,x}=\{(U,s)\mid U\underset{\text{open}}{\subseteq}X,\ s\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)\}$. On $S_{X,x}$, we define the equivalence relation $\sim$ as follows: $(U,s)\sim (U',s')$ if and only if $s|_{U\cap U'}=s'|_{U\cap U'}$. You can then check that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=S_{X,x}/\sim$ is a ring, and this is the stalk. No need to refer to an affine neighbourhood :)

Comment: @imtrying46 but then how do we the stalk is a local ring ?

Comment: By definition of a scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a locally ringed space, such that for every point $x\in X$ there exists an open neighbourhood $U\subseteq X$ of $x$ such that $(U,\mathcal{O}_X|_U)$ is isomorphic to the spectrum of some ring, as locally ringed spaces. By definition of a locally ringed space, the stalks $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, which I defined in my previous comment, are local rings. So this is part of the definition of a scheme :)